Making a custom PopUp that changes height based on content, and adds scroll bar if necerssary
Below are two mock ups I made in paint to showcase what I'm trying to make. I want to build that matches the following criteria:

The horizontal size should be fixed.
The vertical size should be minimum, but can expand if the required.
If the Decription(white section) of the popup increases to the size that it will no longer fit in the screen(with some margin ofc), then a scroll bar should appear.
The size of the Title(yellow section) should not change.
Description could be anything, sometimes text, sometimes another widget, sometimes images.



Here's what I've made so far:

I've made the white section to be a QWidget, for making it easier to swap out a child widget with another.
I've fixed the horizontal width by giving the main frame padding.

I do not know where to go from here. I do not want to use QMessageBox as I want to have complete control over the design and also understand of how everything is working.
Here's the .ui file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Popup</class>
 <widget class="QFrame" name="Popup">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>480</width>
    <height>800</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>480</width>
    <height>800</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Frame</string>
  </property>
  <property name="windowOpacity">
   <double>0.000000000000000</double>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);</string>
  </property>
  <property name="frameShape">
   <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="frameShadow">
   <enum>QFrame::Plain</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="lineWidth">
   <number>0</number>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2" stretch="0,0,0">
   <property name="leftMargin">
    <number>72</number>
   </property>
   <property name="rightMargin">
    <number>72</number>
   </property>
   <item>
    <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>0</width>
       <height>254</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
     <property name="enabled">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="minimumSize">
      <size>
       <width>336</width>
       <height>80</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <property name="maximumSize">
      <size>
       <width>336</width>
       <height>800</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">.QWidget{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,1);
}</string>
     </property>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <property name="spacing">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeConstraint">
       <enum>QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="leftMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="topMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="rightMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="bottomMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="lblTitle">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Ignored" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>0</width>
          <height>80</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <family>Sans Serif</family>
          <pointsize>18</pointsize>
          <bold>true</bold>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">background-color: #FFBF00;
padding:10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;</string>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Lorem Ipsum</string>
        </property>
        <property name="alignment">
         <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
        </property>
        <property name="wordWrap">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_2" native="true">
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">background-color:white</string>
        </property>
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
         <item>
          <widget class="QTextEdit" name="teDescription">
           <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
            <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
            <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
            <enum>QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContents</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="readOnly">
            <bool>true</bool>
           </property>
           <property name="html">
            <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta name=&quot;qrichtext&quot; content=&quot;1&quot; /&gt;&lt;meta charset=&quot;utf-8&quot; /&gt;&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
hr { height: 1px; border-width: 0; }
li.unchecked::marker { content: &quot;\2610&quot;; }
li.checked::marker { content: &quot;\2612&quot;; }
&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body style=&quot; font-family:'Ubuntu'; font-size:11pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;&quot;&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
           </property>
           <property name="textInteractionFlags">
            <set>Qt::NoTextInteraction</set>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>0</width>
       <height>254</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>


Popup class:
header:
#ifndef POPUP_H
#define POPUP_H

#include <QFrame>

namespace Ui {
class Popup;
}

class Popup : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Popup(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void setDescription(const QString &text);
    ~Popup();

private:
    Ui::Popup *ui;
};

#endif // POPUP_H


source:
#include "popup.h"
#include "ui_popup.h"

Popup::Popup(QWidget *parent) :
    QFrame(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Popup)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->teDescription->setFrameStyle(QFrame::NoFrame);
    ui->teDescription->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
}

void Popup::setDescription(const QString &text)
{
    ui->teDescription->setText(text);
}

Popup::~Popup()
{
    delete ui;
}


Main.cpp:
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

#include "popup.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    Popup pop;
    pop.setDescription("This is a \nTest\nto\nsee\n\nhow\nwell it works\nThis is a \nTest\nto\nsee\n\nhow\nwell it works\nThis is a \nTest\nto\nsee\n\nhow\nwell it works\nThis is a \nTest\nto\nsee\n\nhow\nwell it works\nThis is a \nTest\nto\nsee\n\nhow\nwell it works\nThis is a \nTest\nto\nsee\n\nhow\nwell it works\nThis is a \nTest\nto\nsee\n\nhow\nwell it works\nThis is a \nTest\nto\nsee\n\nhow\nwell it works\nThis is a \nTest\nto\nsee\n\nhow\nwell it works\nThis is a \nTest\nto\nsee\n\nhow\nwell it works\nThis is a \nTest\nto\nsee\n\nhow\nwell it works\nThis is a \nTest\nto\nsee\n\nhow\nwell it works\nThis is a \nTest\nto\nsee\n\nhow\nwell it works\n");
    // w.show();
    pop.show();
    w.setGeometry(0,0,480, 800);
    return a.exec();
}


Main Window is default and unused.
This is how it currently looks


What about using, for example, a QTextEdit which already handle the scroll area for you. Then you can also call adjustSize() whenever you want/need.

QAbstractScrollAreas have the sizeAdjustPolicy that suggests a size hint based on the contents if properly set (as long as the contents are correctly set before the outer layout is activated).

@musicamante sizePolicy is possibly one of the most confusing bit that I've encountered in learning Qt so far. I have no idea how any of them work, I usually just toggle through all the combinations until one of them works.
And in this case, I think I'm not able to do the set any sizehint policy correctly

@Fareanor I am using QTextEdit. Which is also part of the problem. I am able to achieve atleast the popup resizing if I use a QLabel instead. But the moment I replace it with a QTextEdit, with the same sizepolicies and everything, it moves back to looking like the image above.

@VisheshVarma please read more carefully, I did not refer to sizePolicy, but sizeAdjustPolicy. Read the link above in the documentation.

@musicamante sorry for not making it clear before. Toggling through them is not making a difference here in my case, only making it even smaller sometimes, maybe because I have Vertical spacers

@VisheshVarma QLabel has some internal mechanisms that may result in some sort of "dynamic" size hint, and QScrollArea bounds the size to the font metrics. Try to subclass QScrollArea and override its sizeHint() in order to return the viewportSizeHint(), also limit the width of the label to an arbitrary size (smaller than the overall width) so that the returned value will fit the contents. Note that by default the sizeHint of a new window will always be reduced to 2/3 of the screen when first mapped, so you should consider using resize() to force it instead.

Note that QML may be better suited to create such a custom popup. Depending on the rest of the project, you may consider completely switching from QtWidgets to QtQuick (QML).

As was clarified in comments, what you want is:

Cover an entire window with a frame.
Inside the frame, center a widget to display a message
The widget centered in the frame should take as little vertical space as possible, with the constraint that it also should show the entire message without any scrollbar whenever possible.

The above 3 points correspond to 3 tasks:

Track the size of the parent window.
Maintain the frame's layout so that the window stays in the center.
Calculate the optimal size of the message.

Based on your question, we can add 2 methods to the Popup class. They will be in charge of tasks 1 and 3. An event filter is installed on the parent to adjust the size automatically, making it 3 methods in total.
popup.h
#ifndef POPUP_H
#define POPUP_H

#include <QtWidgets/QFrame>

namespace Ui {
    class Popup;
}

class Popup : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Popup(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    void setDescription(const QString& text);
    ~Popup();
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event) override;
    void resizeToParent();
    void resizeTextArea();
private:
    Ui::Popup* ui;
    float heightLimitRatio;
    int cachedMinHeight;
};

#endif // POPUP_H

Notes:

heightLimitRatio is used as a constraint on the maximum height, to limit the message window to x% of the window's height.I let you implement the getter/setter for this property.
Regarding the minimum height, since adjusting the height of the widget is done using setFixedHeight, it gets overwritten immediately. Howver, using resize instead would not cause the layout to keep the widget centered.As a result, we need cachedMinHeight to save the minimum height set on the text area.

In popup.cpp, we define the 3 methods (including the event filter), but also add some code to the constructor, for it to fix the state of the window on the first paint event.
If the widget is constructed without a parent, no event filter is installed.
Popup::Popup(QWidget* parent) :
    QFrame(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Popup),
    heightLimitRatio(.85),
    cachedMinHeight(0)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->teDescription->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    cachedMinHeight = ui->teDescription->minimumHeight();

    if (parent)
        parent->installEventFilter(this);

    QObject::connect(ui->teDescription, &QTextEdit::textChanged, this, &Popup::resizeTextArea);
    resizeTextArea();
}

bool Popup::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event)
{
    switch (event->type()) {
        case QEvent::Resize:
        case QEvent::Paint:
            resizeToParent();
    }
    return false;
}

void Popup::resizeToParent()
{
    if (auto parentWidget = static_cast<QWidget*>(parent()); parentWidget) {
        if (size() != parentWidget->size()) {
            setFixedSize(parentWidget->size());
            resizeTextArea(); // The parent may be too small now.
        }
    }
}
void Popup::resizeTextArea()
{
    QMargins extMargins = contentsMargins() + layout()->contentsMargins() + ui->teArea->contentsMargins() + ui->teArea->layout()->contentsMargins(),
             docMargins = ui->teDescription->contentsMargins();

    int minHeight = cachedMinHeight,
        maxHeight = (height() - ui->lblTitle->height() - extMargins.top() - extMargins.bottom()) * heightLimitRatio;
    if (maxHeight < minHeight)
        minHeight = maxHeight; //The window was resized and does not leave enough space for the text anymore

    // To uncomment for nicer behavior when the text edit is not read only.
    //ui->teDescription->setFixedHeight(minHeight); 

    auto document = ui->teDescription->document();
    int height = document->size().height() + docMargins.top() + docMargins.bottom();
    height = std::clamp(height, minHeight, maxHeight); // #include <algorithm>

    if (height != ui->teDescription->height()) // Better to avoid resizing when unnecessary.
        ui->teDescription->setFixedHeight(height);
}

All that is left is task 2: maintain the widget in the center of the frame.
Compared to the .ui file in the question, only a few changes were required:

The size policies of the widgets were modified and it was centered in the layout.I for one do not consider the use of spacers less elegant but it is indeed true you do not need them if you set the layout aligment of the widget inside the frame.
The layout size constraint of all the layouts were reset to SetDefaultConstraint
The stylesheets (especially the border radius) of the widgets were adjusted a bit. It makes a small difference if you were to shrink the parent window to the point the text cannot be displayed.
A couple corrections have been implemented, such as clearing the spaces/line breaks you had saved in the text edit.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Popup</class>
 <widget class="QFrame" name="Popup">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>480</width>
    <height>800</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>480</width>
    <height>800</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Frame</string>
  </property>
  <property name="windowOpacity">
   <double>0.000000000000000</double>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);</string>
  </property>
  <property name="frameShape">
   <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="frameShadow">
   <enum>QFrame::Plain</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="lineWidth">
   <number>0</number>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2" stretch="0">
   <property name="spacing">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="leftMargin">
    <number>72</number>
   </property>
   <property name="rightMargin">
    <number>72</number>
   </property>
   <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter|Qt::AlignVCenter">
    <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
     <property name="enabled">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="sizePolicy">
      <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
       <horstretch>0</horstretch>
       <verstretch>0</verstretch>
      </sizepolicy>
     </property>
     <property name="minimumSize">
      <size>
       <width>336</width>
       <height>80</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <property name="maximumSize">
      <size>
       <width>336</width>
       <height>16777215</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">.QWidget{
              border-radius: 10px;
              background-color: white;
}
            </string>
     </property>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout" stretch="0,1">
      <property name="spacing">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeConstraint">
       <enum>QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="leftMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="topMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="rightMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="bottomMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="lblTitle">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Ignored" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>0</width>
          <height>80</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>16777215</width>
          <height>80</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <family>Sans Serif</family>
          <pointsize>18</pointsize>
          <bold>true</bold>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">background-color: #FFBF00;
padding:10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
                  </string>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Lorem Ipsum</string>
        </property>
        <property name="alignment">
         <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
        </property>
        <property name="wordWrap">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="teArea" native="true">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Ignored" vsizetype="Preferred">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>80</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
background-color:white;</string>
        </property>
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
         <property name="spacing">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <item alignment="Qt::AlignVCenter">
          <widget class="QTextEdit" name="teDescription">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="frameShape">
            <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
            <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
            <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
            <enum>QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContents</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="readOnly">
            <bool>true</bool>
           </property>
           <property name="html">
            <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta name=&quot;qrichtext&quot; content=&quot;1&quot; /&gt;&lt;meta charset=&quot;utf-8&quot; /&gt;&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
hr { height: 1px; border-width: 0; }
li.unchecked::marker { content: &quot;\2610&quot;; }
li.checked::marker { content: &quot;\2612&quot;; }
&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body style=&quot; font-family:'Segoe UI'; font-size:9pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;&quot;&gt;
&lt;p style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
           </property>
           <property name="textInteractionFlags">
            <set>Qt::TextSelectableByMouse</set>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>



The OP doesn't set a maximum size for teDescription (then it's the default 16777215), so this may become problematic as it doesn't consider screen size. Since it seems that the text won't be changed while visible, a more appropriate approach could rely on overriding sizeHint() on the QTextEdit or, even better, heightForWidth() (since the OP wants a fixed width), but unfortunately this limits the height to 2/3 of the screen size. Another alternative could be to set a maximum height based on the QWidget's screen() for the whole window, and setting the minimum based on the document.

That's true... But it is a complicated topic for desktops with non-uniform screen configuration and the gray area in the widget made me suspect the popup was to cover an existing window, in which case looking at the screen is unnecessary. I edited my answer to show what needs to be changed in case the popup must exist as a window. Even then, I'd usually approach the topic of maximum size with a reasonable hardcoded value; it does not look like the popup must be designed to fit exactly in screen). I'll see if OP has some feedback regarding that.

Qt normally uses QGuiApplication::screenAt() (possibly based on the center of the widget or window) to define geometries that require screen coordinates. The OP says that it should try to fit within the screen size, and eventually show the vertical scroll bar. Yet, some aspects are indeed unclear (that's why we should normally ask for related clarifications before answering), but if the widget does base its maximum size on the screen, using QScreen capabilities should be the preferred choice.

Yes, the popup is only meant to be shown over an existing window. The grey indicates a low opacity backdrop to indicate that the parent window is inactive(Which is something I can do manually during function call).
The maximum width and height of the window is to be around 85%.

Using the example shared, I was able to adjust the size of the QTextEdit, but its parent widget was not resizing itself to the minimum possible. For doing that, I added vertical spacers above and below. I don't see this as being the most elegant way of achieving this but I am out of ideas. What else can I do here?

OK, I adjusted the answer by quite a bit to reflect the added information from your comments. Give it a try.
